# I need PHP Mail hide other recipient addresses on multiple email sends

Tags: php, phpmailer, php-7

I have a PHP script which sends an e-card to multiple recipients in function calls (takes an array of comma-separated email addresses and mail()s to each one individually). However, when looking at the received email, each client can see the other addresses that the email was sent to, making me believe they are all being sent in one email, despite the separate mail() calls. Here is my current code:

```php
$to = "email1@example.com, email2@example.com,email3@example.com";

$subject = "subject";

$message = "This is body";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";

$status =  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Where is this PHPMailer?

Comment: i have used simple mail function.

Comment: You need to create a foreach() loop and go through the email addresses to run this separately,

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use a **library**, for example [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and then you can set the **BCC** (Blind Carbon Copy), so they can't see the other e-mail-adresses.

PHPMailer has many more advantages, to name a few:

- SMTP support
- Attachments
- Protect against header injection attacks

---

Otherwise you could loop the whole process and only send to one e-mail-address at once, but that isn't really performant.

Comment: Dead right. PHPMailer also provides docs and code exampleS of how to send to mailing lists efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

add null at the mail function and resiptients see only the sender

```html
$mrows = $sql->execute("SELECT email FROM email", SQL_RETURN_ASSOC);

$mnum = sizeof ($mrows);  

 // get the email address for who we are sending this email to.
 for ( $mi = 0; $mi < $mnum; ++$mi )
      {
       $email = $mrows [ $mi ] [ "email" ];     
       @$bcc_emails .= "".$email.", ";
      }     
 
 @$bcc_emails .= "".$email.", ";
 $headers .= "BCC: ".$bcc_emails."\n";
 mail(null, $email_subject, $email_text, $headers);
```